# What is the best way to store logs for future data reports (Ex: each year) using a Loki stack?

Tags: logging, cassandra, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I am currently using a loki stack (Grafana-Loki-Promtail) for logs analysis.
But I need a solution to store the logs for multiple years (can I do this on Loki? I cannot use a cloud solution) to do reports.

Currently my loki container stores the data on its filesystem, which doesn't seem like a good long term solution.

I also saw that I cannot query all the logs at once (the queries are limited to 5000)

Should i use a DB with Loki to store the logs? which ones are compatible? (I saw that there is one called Cassandra)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Keeping your logs for several years and run instant report on them is a tough challenge. You would need to pay extra to keep a huge index, no matter what is the software. Is your report giving numerical values ? I suppose you don't put logs line for stuff happening years ago right ?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use a cloud solution

You cannot use cloud solutions to store the long-term logs? Or to process logs at all (e.g. run Loki in cloud).

Asking because [Grafana Cloud Logs](https://grafana.com/products/cloud/logs/) has a [log exporter](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/data-configuration/logs/export/) functionality for this exact use case.

Alternatively, you will likely need to configure your [retention period](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/) for as much time as you want to have your logs around.